# cut/paste some cells in a row with today's date in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, copy-paste

I need to copy values of some cells within a row that has today's date and after copying clears the data of some cells in the source sheet. I have searched many similar questions but most relates to moving a whole row to new sheet and can't adapt to my needs.

I'm providing a sample sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uOswjZ24_0RVgPiHnD662T9Rl3zm4g7qmn7e9HjmqZk/edit#gid=1450205890

The sheet "OUT" is split into 2 parts: on top is the copied data then under the black row there's a formula to provide a sorted view of the check outs coming up. If having the check out view after the black row creates more issues I can ged rid of this part but would like to keep it if possible.

To resume what I need:

If Col35 has today's date in "ROOMS",

Copy to "OUT" in ColB and in the first empty row on top of black row (in this order):R,AH,AJ,AL,W:Y,AN,T,U,F:Q (highlighted in yellow in sample sheet)

Then in "ROOMS", clear cells F:Q,T,U,AH,AK:AQ,AS,AU,AV ( Highlighted in orange on sample sheet)

If the script can add an empty row automatically after copying all the ranges this way it would always have an empty row to copy to.

My question was also posted and edited on https://support.google.com/docs/thread/201627194

The following code I've started with copies exactly but does not clear data in cells afterwards

```
    function copyrange() {
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName('ROOMS');
      var vA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      var csh=ss.getSheetByName('OUT');
      var found=false;
      var dt=new Date();
      var today=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight
      var output=[];
      for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
       var date=new Date(vA[i][35]);//can be a string the constructor recognizes or a date
       var dv=new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight
    if (dv==today) {
      output.push([vA[i][17],vA[i][33],vA[i][35],vA[i][37],vA[i][22],vA[i][23],vA[i][24],vA[i][39],vA[i][19],vA[i][20],vA[i][5],vA[i][6],vA[i][7],vA[i][8],vA[i][9],vA[i][10],vA[i][11],vA[i][12],vA[i][13],vA[i][14],vA[i][15],vA[i][16]]);
      var found=true;
    }
  }
  if(found) {
csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,+2,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }
}
```

Comment: Exact copy of [cut/paste some cells in a row with today's date in another sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/201627194).

Comment: is this a problem that one person tries to get help from different websites ? not sure what's the point of your comment ?

Comment: The point is to avoid wasted cycles. When you post a question on many sites, many contributors may unnecessarily spend time researching your problem when a solution has already have been posted by someone else on another site. You should show these people some respect that and explicitly link to other sites where you have crossposted to avoid those wasted cycles and frustration. See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: Didn't mean to disrespect anyone. I'm not an expert and couldn't possibly have known the same people are working to help on different websites and cross posting could be an issue. I'm still not getting anyone to help me on both sites. I have edited my post though and I understand your position as well of course. Anyway I hope someone can help me with my issue

Comment: It does not matter whether it is the same people or not. Crossposting still causes wasted cycles. Always link to other sites where you have posted, and sites you have come across that contain partial solutions or information relevant to possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

> also clears the cells in the source sheet (ROOMS) and everyday as soon as the date changes to TODAY

You should probably run the function on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) once a day right after midnight.

Use `Array.map()`, `Array.filter()`, `Utilities.formatDate()` and `Sheet.deleteRows()`, like this:

```js
'use strict';

/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function moveTodayRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ROOMS');
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of OUT');
  const columnsToCopy = [
    17, 33, 35, 37, 22, 23, 24, 39, 19, 20, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
  ];
  if (!sourceSheet || !targetSheet) {
    throw new Error('There is no sheet by that name.');
  }
  const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const isoFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
  const todayString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, isoFormat);
  const values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const matchingRowNumbers = values.map((row, index) =>
    todayString === Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[35]), timezone, isoFormat)
      ? index + 1
      : null
  );
  const result = values
    .filter((row, index) => matchingRowNumbers.includes(index))
    .map(row => columnsToCopy.map(columnIndex => row[columnIndex]));
  let message = 'Found no rows to move.';
  if (result.length) {
    appendRows_(targetSheet, result, 2);
    deleteRows_(sourceSheet, matchingRowNumbers);
    message = `Moved ${result.length} rows.`;
  }
  console.log(message);
  ss.toast(message);
}


/**
* Appends an array or a value to the bottom of a sheet starting in
* the given column after the last row where the column is blank.
*
* When optColumn is provided, appends data starting in that column
* after the last row where that column has visible content.
*
* When optColumn is not provided, appends data starting in column A
* after the last row that has visible content in any column.
*
* Use Range.getRichTextValues() to preserve text formatting such as bold,
* italic, underlined, font and text colors when appending textual data.
* To append numbers, dates and plain text, use Range.getValues().
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet A spreadsheet sheet to append the data to.
* @param {Object[][]} data The plain or formatted data to append: a 2D array, a 1D array or a single value.
* @param {Number} optColumn Optional. The column number where to start appending the data. Defaults to 1.
* @return {Object} An object with fields {Range} range, {Number} rowStart, columnStart, numRows, numColumns.
*/
function appendRows_(sheet, data, optColumn) {
  // version 1.10, written by --Hyde, 15 June 2022
  if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
    data = [[data]];
  } else if (!Array.isArray(data[0])) {
    data = [data];
  }
  let action = 'setValues';
  if (data.some(row => row.some(value => value.getRuns))) {
    action = 'setRichTextValues';
    data = data.map(row => row.map(value => value.getRuns
      ? value
      : SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(value).build()
    ));
  }
  const rowStart = getLastRow_(sheet, optColumn) + 1;
  const columnStart = Number(optColumn) || 1;
  const numRows = data.length;
  const numColumns = data[0].length;
  const range = sheet.getRange(rowStart, columnStart, numRows, numColumns);
  range[action](data);
  return { range: range, rowStart: rowStart, columnStart: columnStart, numRows: numRows, numColumns: numColumns };
}


/**
* Gets the position of the last row that has visible content in a column of the sheet.
* When column is undefined, returns the last row that has visible content in any column.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet A sheet in a spreadsheet.
* @param {Number} columnNumber Optional. The 1-indexed position of a column in the sheet.
* @return {Number} The 1-indexed row number of the last row that has visible content.
*/
function getLastRow_(sheet, columnNumber) {
  // version 1.5, written by --Hyde, 4 April 2021
  const values = (
    columnNumber
      ? sheet.getRange(1, columnNumber, sheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1)
      : sheet.getDataRange()
  ).getDisplayValues();
  let row = values.length - 1;
  while (row && !values[row].join('')) row--;
  return row + 1;
}


/**
* Deletes from a sheet the rows whose row numbers are given in an array.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet A spreadsheet sheet where to delete rows.
* @param {Number[]} rowsToDelete The rows to delete, identified by 1-indexed row numbers.
* @return {Number} The count of delete operations done, i.e., number of the consecutive row runs deleted from the sheet.
*/
function deleteRows_(sheet, rowsToDelete) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 21 August 2022
  const rowNumbers = rowsToDelete.filter((value, index, array) => array.indexOf(value) === index);
  const runLengths = getRunLengths_(rowNumbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));
  for (let i = runLengths.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sheet.deleteRows(runLengths[i][0], runLengths[i][1]);
  }
  return runLengths.length;
}


/**
* Counts consecutive numbers in an array and returns a 2D array that
* lists the first number of each run and the number of items in each run.
*
* The numbers array [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 5, 4] will get
* the result [[1, 3], [5, 1], [8, 2], [11, 3], [5, 1], [4, 1]].
*
* For best results, sort the numbers array like this:
* const runLengths = getRunLengths_(numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));
* Note that duplicate values in numbers will give duplicates in result.
*
* @param {Number[]} numbers The numbers to group into runs.
* @return {Number[][]} The numbers grouped into runs, or [] if the array is empty.
*/
function getRunLengths_(numbers) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 31 May 2021
  if (!numbers.length) {
    return [];
  }
  return numbers.reduce((accumulator, value, index) => {
    if (!index || value !== 1 + numbers[index - 1]) {
      accumulator.push([value]);
    }
    const lastIndex = accumulator.length - 1;
    accumulator[lastIndex][1] = (accumulator[lastIndex][1] || 0) + 1;
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for working on this I appreciate. I've edited my post as reading it again seemed not to describe properly my needs. I hope I've explained better this time and provided sample sheet. Your proposed script copies data needed but puts it on first row of sheet overwriting the existing data which is 2 frozen rows header and then delete the whole row in "ROOMS" instead of just certain cells. it also throws an error but works regardless of it

Comment: Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.